# How do I detect if a line in a string has nothing but line carriage(s)?

Tags: ruby

I have a string that has multiple lines. What I am doing is checking each line for specific characteristics and then treating them accordingly.

One characteristic is if the line begins with a `+` or a `-`. That works just fine.

Another characteristic is if it contains nothing but a `\n`, but I am not sure how to check for that.

Here is an example of a string:

```
 "+        end\n",
 " \n",
 "-      # Specifies a many-to-many relationship with another class. This associates two classes via an\n",
```

I have some simple checks that detect the first & last line, that look like this `<% if line.start_with?("-") %>`.

But not quite sure how to check to see if the line ONLY has a (or multiple) `\n`. Note that other lines can have `\n` in that line and should NOT trigger this condition (like the first & last line).

The key thing is if the line contains ONLY line carriage returns `\n`.

**Edit 1**

Note that I am not trying to remove those lines. I am simply looking for a regex or perhaps a built in ruby function that will help me easily identify the lines that fit the above condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are possibly looking for a `String#strip`, which returns a copy of string with leading and trailing whitespace removed:

```
def if_empty?(string)
  string.strip.empty?
end

if_empty?(" \n\n\n\n")
=> true
```

Comment: Nope....I am looking for a regex or some other matcher tool that will help me identify the strings that only have `\n\n\n\n`. I don't want to strip them. I want to just identify them.

Comment: you can just identify by checking if string empty after `strip`.BTW, your instance has not only '\n' and `strip` can handle this.

Comment: Actually you are right.....my bad. Your use of `strip.empty?` works. Genius. Thanks much meng!

Comment: I have one more string type I am trying to detect. Do you mind looking at that one too? I am going to create a new question and post the link here in the comments, cool?

Comment: Sure, no probs.

Comment: `str.strip.empty? => true` implies the string `str` contains only whitespace, not one or more `\n`'s only. I'm sure you know that. Ref [String#strip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-strip).

Comment: @Ilya here is the URL to the other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42758179/how-do-i-detect-the-presence-of-this-line

Comment: @CarySwoveland So what is the equivalent that detects one or more `\n`'s?

Comment: Ilya actually did a clever hack, where we aren't checking for the presence of `\n`'s, we are stripping them from the line and checking to see if the line is empty. That produces the same result.

Comment: mac, `str.squeeze == "\n"` or `str =~ /\A\n+\z/`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I assumed that requirements a little bit different because of instance (" \n")

Comment: @CarySwoveland What will that catch that Ilya's own won't?

Comment: @marcamillion, its catch if string consists of only `\n` chars, but your instance has also whitespace.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It wasn't a typo. That's the actual string I want to parse and catch. So it can also have a whitespace, along with a `\n`. I should have been more clear.

Comment: llya, feel free to use that code, but it's now clear that your interpretation of the question was correct.