# How do I detect the presence of this line?

Tags: ruby, string

This question is related to a previous one I just [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757894/how-do-i-detect-if-a-line-in-a-string-has-nothing-but-line-carriages), so forgive me if much of the language seems similar.

I have a string that has multiple lines. What I am doing is checking each line for specific characteristics and then treating them accordingly.

- One characteristic is if the line begins with a `+` or a `-`. That works just fine.
- Another characteristic is if it contains nothing but a `\n`, and Ilya helped me figure out how to detect those lines, so that's good.
- The last type of string I am trying to detect is those that don't match any of the above criteria, but come AFTER a line that begins with either a `-` or `+`.

Taken out of context, this is an example of a valid string I would like to find: `"         end\n",`

However, here is a more complete example within the context of being after a line that begins with `+` or `-`.

```
"+          Reflection.add_reflection self, name, reflection\n",
 "         end\n",
 " \n",
 "-        habtm_reflection = ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasAndBelongsToManyReflection.new(name, scope, options, self)\n",
```

In this particular instance, I am trying to pick out the second line.

Here is an instance where strings that match the pure string matching parameter would be disqualified because they come BEFORE a string that starts with a `-` or a `+`.

```
 "     #\n",
 "     # All of the association macros can be specialized through options. This makes cases\n",
 "     # more complex than the simple and guessable ones possible.\n",
 "-    module ClassMethods\n",
```

I hope that's clear.

**Edit 1**

To provide more clarity on what I am looking for. Basically I have broken the string into a bunch of lines and then I am iterating over each line.

So this is what I have done:

```
  <% diff.body.lines.each do |dl| %>
    <% if dl.start_with?("-") %>
    <% elsif dl.start_with?("+") %>
    <% elsif dl.strip.empty? %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

So what I want to do is to either modify the above set of `if` statements to accommodate this latest line check, or find some way to check it by adding another `elsif` condition....although considering that I need to know what happened to the line above I am not seeing how to do that without modifying this `if` statement.

Comment: Where does that file come from?

Answer (score 2):

```
str = [
  "+          Reflection ...\n",
  "         end\n",
  " \n",
  "-        habtm_reflection = ...\n"].join

str[/(^[+-].*$)\n(?!\n)(^[^+-].*$)/, 2]
#⇒ "         end"
```

The regular expression basically looks up the line that is started with either `+` ot `-` (with `(^[+-].*$)`), skips the `\n` and then matches the line that is not started with one of `+` or `-` (with `(^[^+-].*$)`.)

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for what this is doing please?

Comment: Oh I see what you are doing, perhaps the way I imagined it to work can't work. The issue is that I am parsing this string on a line by line basis. Ok hang on, I have to rewrite the question to better reflect how I am parsing each line.

Comment: This is pretty clear regular expression, I am in doubt what could be clarified here.

Comment: It's not about the RegEx. The Regex is good. The issue is the way I am parsing the lines. The long and short of it is that by the time the iterator gets to evaluate this line: ` "         end\n",` that's all it sees. It doesn't see the line before. I have updated the question to add more details about my current approach. In other words, if it were just 1 string like the example you created, your version would work perfectly. But because I am parsing the string line by line, it won't work for me. But a great start though!

Comment: Use [`Enumerable#each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) then: `lines.each_cons(2).select { |prev, curr| has_plus_minus(prev), is_not_empty(curr)}.map(&:last)`. I won’t change the answer itself, since it perfectly answers the question stated.

Comment: Given that I have updated the question, the current answer doesn't actually answer the question. Please update it properly.

Comment: Given that the question clearly states “I have a string that has multiple lines.” this answer still perfectly fits the question.